# Is there a shortcut or way to switch to the last open notebook in Onenote

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, microsoft-onenote

I often need to write a quick note in a OneNote notebook other then the one I am in at the time. If I flick over to the one I want, it takes a little while to go back to which ever one I was working on, especially if I'm in the maximized view, or if I have OneNote docked to half screen.

When coding in Visual Studio, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> takes you back to the last area you were working on, even if that is in another code file. Is there something similar in OneNote?

I like that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between open sections, but that doesn't help if the page you were last editing is in a different notebook all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same shortcuts as in Internet Explorer: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to go Back and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to go Forward.

If you like the mouse better, you can customize the Quick Access Toolbar to add Back and Forward buttons, including a history drop-down, if desired.